# Add $scope to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller

May be is a stupid question... but I wanna make best practices. So.. I have my controller:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('example.cancha')
    .controller('CanchaController', CanchaController);

CanchaController.$inject = ['$state', 'canchaService'];

function CanchaController($state, canchaService) {
    var vm = angular.extend(this, {
        canchasComplejo: []
        });



    (function activate() {
        cargarCanchasComplejo();
    })();

    //funcion que llama al servicio para obtener las canchas del complejo
    function cargarCanchasComplejo() {
        canchaService.obtenerCanchasComplejo()
            .then(function(canchasComplejo) {
                vm.canchasComplejo = canchasComplejo;
        });
    }
}
})();
```

Now I need to call a function and make changes (is a collapse list) with

```
   ng-click="toggleGroup(group)"

   ng-class="{active: isGroupShown(group)}".
```

**For this I need to use $scope**
**How can I integrate in my controller the $scope? Because I the most controller are like:**

```
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    ... 
});
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: read some articles on *"angular controllerAs"*. You are mixing methodologies of `$scope vs controllerAs`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can inject $scope in the same way you are inject **$state** so:

```
CanchaController.$inject = ['$state', '$scope', 'canchaService'];

function CanchaController($state, $scope, canchaService) { ...
```

Comment: please, try to answer my question (is asociate with this post) in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39886765/expandable-list-in-ionic

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject the $scope with $inject

Ex:

```
(function () {

    angular
        .module('example.cancha')
        .controller('CanchaController', CanchaController);

    CanchaController.$inject = ['$state', 'canchaService','$scope'];
    function CanchaController($state,canchaService,$scope) {
// you can call function here with $scope enter code here
      $scope.xyz = function(){

        }
    }
})();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.controller('CanchaController',function($scope,$state, canchaService) {
    var vm = angular.extend(this, {
        canchasComplejo: []
        });

CanchaController.$inject = ['$scope','$state', 'canchaService'];
```

You can try this